# Play Java validation fail for Set and Map

Tags: java, validation, playframework-2.0

I use Play 2.5.12 to provide a web service to create an object and validate its attributes. Here is a simplified code of what I want to do:

```
public class Example {

    private String lastName;

    private List<String> firstNames;

    private Map<String, Integer> vehicles;

    public Example() {}

    public String validate() {
        if (vehicles.get("Ferrari") != null)
            return "Liar!";
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new ToStringBuilder(this).append(lastName).append(firstNames).append(vehicles).toString();
    }

    // getters and setters
}


public class ExampleController extends Controller {

    private FormFactory formFactory;

    @Inject
    public ExampleController(FormFactory formFactory) {
        this.formFactory = formFactory;
    }

    @BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
    public Result createExample() {
        Example exampleFromJackson = Json.fromJson(request().body().asJson(), Example.class);
        System.out.println(exampleFromJackson.toString());
        Example exampleFromForm = formFactory.form(Example.class).bindFromRequest().get();
        System.out.println(exampleFromForm.toString());
        // etc
        return created();
    }
}
```

If I call the web service with a body like this:

```
{
    "lastName": "Martin",
    "firstNames": ["Robert", "Cecil"],
    "vehicles": {
        "BMW": 1,
        "Seat": 1
    }
}
```

The deserialized object by jackson prints correctly then this error occurs:

```
org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'firstNames[0]' of bean class [models.Example]: Property referenced in indexed property path 'firstNames[0]' is neither an array nor a List nor a Map; returned value was [[]]
```

If I replace the Set by a List, I can avoid this error and then I obtain the following:

```
models.Example@68d2162a[Martin,[Robert, Cecil],{BMW=1, Seat=1}]
models.Example@29ef1c11[Martin,[Robert, Cecil],{}]
```

The deserialized object by jackson is correct but the one obtained by the request isn't so I can't do a correct validation.

**So my questions are:

- Why Play doesn't let me use a Set?

- Why is the Map not retrieved?**